# EPUB3 Input data and save them somewhere

Tags: javascript, java, android, mysql, epub3

So I'm looking for a way to get some kind of form into an EPUB3 Book that allows the user to enter some data for example his first name and last name. 
After submitting this data has to be saved somewhere, best case would be a database like MySQL. 
Worst Case data is being saved locally and the EPUB3 Reader App I am using is getting a function call to work with the data.

So is there anyway get this done on best case?
Or is it even possible for the worst case? I'm using an EPUB3 Reader App that is still on development, it is based on Java. Is there any way to get an interface between app and Ebook?

I do not require full functioning code here just some hints on how it might work out

Answer (score 0):

For the worst-case side of this, saving the information locally, you can use "localstorage", for info on that go here: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html.

The next part is not so simple: you could use some sort of XHR request, but chances are that won't work because most ePub3 readers don't support XHR or external request functionality.

If you want your book to be distributed through any of the "normal" channels (pretty much just iBooks since you need Script support at this point) you won't be able to send the data externally...

However, if you will be distributing the book yourself for use on Readium and iBooks (or if you want to plan ahead and hope for support) there are a few hacks you can do. My personal favorite, is embedding the data in a media request (IE www.yoursite.com/fake.m4v?data1=localStorage.data1&data2=localStorage.data2) and pulling out the data on your server. This would be nested in a try catch and activated whenever the book is opened. If you include the base url (www.yoursite.com) in the .opf file, as well as at some point in the chapter which contains the script, this will work in iBooks! If you don't include it in the .opf the request will get blocked right out of the gate... Again, this "solution" is just a hack and it won't work through "normal" distribution channels and all of this is entirely dependent on the reader app you are using.

Best of luck!!!